# how could I run/execute a text file as a exe using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, exe

I need to know how I could make a batch file that would execute / run a txt file as if it was an exe file. Does any one know what I could do or try. I am using windows 7 ultimate 32 bit. The txt file is an exe just with the .txt extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an EXE, why is it named `.txt`?

Sometimes EXEs are renamed to be able to send them per EMail (some Email-servers are blocking EXEs for security reasons)

Best way is to rename it to `.exe`

If you really want to stay it as `.txt` make a copy:

```
copy file.txt file.exe
file.exe
```

Note: Don't run any executable if you don't fully trust the source!

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to alter the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command` registry key to change what happens when .txt files are opened.

The default setting is to open with notepad.exe

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

Another way could be to rename the file to.exe, run it, rename it .txt when finished.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for copying the .txt file to a .exe extension.

- This only works if the file is executable

Simply put in batch script:

```
call yourfilename.txt
```

or just open CMD and type the same thing, this works only if the .exe file
was renamed to .txt extension, same works as for .run, .dat, .bin, .bmp and
so on, for example:

```
call chrome.x
```

or lets try starting CMD with .bmp extension

```
call cmd.bmp
```

- This will work on all the files that have executable code, other files will not work!

Comment: You don't need to use `call`, [any files with `MZ` signature will be treated as an exe file](https://superuser.com/a/690608/241386)

Comment: Indeed. I did stated that "This will work on all the files that have executable code" so It counts like the same, but your info is pretty useful. Though trying to launch "chrome.x" doesn't work but "call "chrome.x"" does so it could be fault in the old non-up-to-date Windows (which I had during the writing of this post)